# Why are print and return giving me different results?

Tags: python, list, printing, return

I'm using a Python script to calculate Pascal's Triangles for various modulos, and then spit out formatted strings that Lilypond can read. This is for a piece of music.

I can get my triangles to print perfectly, using this:

```
rows_and_mod = 2
rows = rows_and_mod ** 2

def lily_string(rows):
    for rownum in range (rows):
        newValue=1
        PrintingList = [newValue]
        for iteration in range (rownum):
            newValue = newValue * (rownum-iteration) * 1 / ( iteration + 1 )
            PrintingList.append(int(newValue % rows_and_mod))
    for n,i in enumerate(PrintingList):
        if i==0:
            PrintingList[n]='r8'
        elif i==1:
            PrintingList[n]='g8'
        elif i==2:
            PrintingList[n]="b16 b"
        elif i==3:
            PrintingList[n]="\\tuplet 3/2 { d'16 d' d' }"
        elif i==4:
            PrintingList[n]="f'32 f' f' f'"
    formatted_tri = " ".join(PrintingList)
    print formatted_tri

final_tri = lily_string(rows)
```

Which prints:

g8
g8 g8
g8 r8 g8
g8 g8 g8 g8

But when I replace the print at the end with a return, it only gives me back the first item of the list. For instance:

```
    formatted_tri = " ".join(PrintingList)
    return formatted_tri

final_tri = lily_string(rows)

print final_tri
```

Prints only a single g8.

I figure I must be missing something on how to use or place Return.

Comment: I guess a more accurate question on my part, then, would be "why is return only giving me the first item in the list?" I think it might be interrupting the for loop, but am not sure (and can't figure out how to fix it).

Comment: I've tried to run your code and it only prints the last line `g8 g8 g8 g8` with both options

Comment: @RubenBermudez: I think that's an indentation issue.

Comment: @user2357112, yes, lines `formatted_tri = " ".join(PrintingList)
print formatted_tri ` should be inside loop to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @RubenBermudez: I checked in the edit view. It's a mixed tabs and spaces problem.

Comment: @RubenBermudez I was having a bit of trouble formatting this in the edit box. First post, sorry!

Comment: @NickWritesMusic no problem, just fix it so the question remains correctly formated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return` ends the function immediately. This is significantly more obvious when it's just `return`, with no argument. A function call can only execute a single `return`, because once it does, it's gone.

```
>>> def f():
...     print 1
...     return
...
...     # Doesn't happen.
...     print 2
...
>>> f()
1
```

If you want to send output out of your program (for example, so Lilypond can use it), you want `print`. If you want to send data to the part of your program that called the function, you want `return`. Here, you want `print`. If you want to perform further processing on the string inside your Python program, you'll want to instead `return` a single string or a list of strings.

Finally, you've mixed tabs and spaces for indentation. If you keep doing that, you'll run into weird bugs where certain parts of your program are executed at the wrong times, too many times, or not at all, and after many hours of frustration, you'll find that Python was reading your indentation differently from how you were reading it. Avoid those problems; don't mix tabs and spaces.

Comment: Thanks very much, that explains `return` much better. In this case, when I then plug the function in (using a `%` operator) to the Lilypond output, it returns "None."

Relevant code is here:
`f1.write('''{%r}
\\header {
    piece = "%s."
  }
''' % (lily_string(rows), modulo))`

Any ideas?

Comment: @NickWritesMusic: If you want to perform further processing on your text (such as inserting it into a larger string with `%`), you want to build one big string and `return` it instead of `print`ing it incrementally. `print` sends data to an external receiver.

Comment: so something like concatenating all the lines it would print into one, and then returning that might be the way to go?

Comment: @NickWritesMusic: Yup.

Comment: Alright, I ended up using `yield`. I'm not 100% on how it works, but it output the list without breaking the loop, so I'm happy!